# Selection variable expressions fields are not working in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I properly define everything in my back end file. When I try to use
the back end variables in Thymeleaf by using selection variable
expression it is not working. It show errors in every field:

```
cannot resolve field name
```

register.html

```
<!doctype html "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:replace="/fragments/head"></head>

<body>

<nav th:replace="/fragments/nav :: nav-front"></nav>

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div th:replace="/fragments/categories"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3 class="display-4">Register</h3>

            <form method="post" th:object="${user}" th:action="@{/register}" >

                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" class="alert alert-danger">
                    There are errors
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for>Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}" placeholder="Username">
                    <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}">
                    <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for>Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{confirmPassword}">
                    <span class="error" th:if="${passwordMatchProblem}">Passwords do not match</span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for>E-mail:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                    <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for>Phone number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" placeholder="Phone number">
                    <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('phoneNumber')}" th:errors="*{phoneNumber}"></span>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-danger mb-5">Register</button>

            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="/fragments/footer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I get errors everywhere I use the selection expression field.

Comment: Small point: In Thymeleaf there are variable expression: `${...}`, and there are selection expressions `*{...}`. Are you referring to both types in your question ("_selection expression fields_")? Or just one of them?

Comment: Please also [edit] your question to show the full text of the error you are getting. I don't see a `name` field in the sample template.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding `"user"` to your model in your controller?
You need to add it to your model so Thymeleaf can access it.
`addAttribute` method can be used like so: `model.addAttribute("user", myUser);`

Comment: I added user  model in controller ,but I am not able to access user elements in register page

Comment: Please provide the full error log. I cannot find any log that is "cannot resolve field name" in Thymeleaf.